# Finding conditions using independent events

Tags: probability

There are two questions and the same condition of the events being independent is given, and according to me one of the options is the same, can you help me to differentiate between the two.

This is the first question with a solution-

[image]

**And this is the second question -**

[image]

In the second question, the answer was c as mentioned.

The confusion is :

In the first question, the two sets are given to be independent and in the second question correct options the sets are considered to be independent.

So the condition for both of them is the same.

Then how about the first question option (4) is wrong and for the second one option (3) is right?

Comment: Perhaps you might re-consider option 4, in the first question.  For example, attempt to **randomly** construct two events that are independent, and then see if their complementary events are also independent.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following claim: if events $U$ and $V$ are independent, then $U^c$ and $V^c$ are independent. Hence option 4 is actually correct, whereas option 2 is wrong, since we only have $\mathbb{P}(S\setminus U)=0$, not $S=U$. Proof of the claim: Assume independence of $U$ and $V$, that is $\mathbb{P}(U\cap V)=\mathbb{P}(U)\mathbb{P}(V)$. Then $$\mathbb{P}(U^c\cap V^c)=\mathbb{P}((U\cup V)^c)=1-\mathbb{P}(U\cup V)=1-(\mathbb{P}(U)+\mathbb{P}(V)-\mathbb{P}(U\cap V))=1-(\mathbb{P}(U)+\mathbb{P}(V)-\mathbb{P}(U)\mathbb{P}(V))=1-\mathbb{P}(U)-\mathbb{P}(V)(1-\mathbb{P}(U))=(1-\mathbb{P}(U))(1-\mathbb{P}(V))=\mathbb{P}(U^c)\mathbb{P}(V^c).$$ This shows independenc of $U^c$ and $V^c$. To sum up, option c is correct as stated, but the solution to the first question is wrong, option 4 is the correct one, so no contradiction arises with option c.